# XML filter list on calculated ratio

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with a quite weird XML file. It's a list of most popular books in a library.

Title one has four holds on two items, giving a ratio of two holds/item.
Title two has five holds on one item, giving a ratio of four holds/item, and Title three has a ratio of five holds/item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="holdratio3.xsl"?>
<report>
<title>Individual Item Display</title>
<dateCreated>2016-03-29T16:58:57</dateCreated>
<dateFormat>yyyy/mm/dd</dateFormat>
<catalog>
    <marc>
        <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Title one</marcEntry>
    </marc>
    <call>
        <item>
            <numberOfHolds>4</numberOfHolds>
            <type>LOAN</type>
        </item>
        <item>
            <numberOfHolds>4</numberOfHolds>
            <type>LOAN</type>
        </item>
    </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
    <marc>
        <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Title two</marcEntry>
    </marc>
    <call>
        <item>
            <numberOfHolds>5</numberOfHolds>
            <type>LOAN</type>
        </item>
    </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
    <marc>
        <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Title three</marcEntry>
    </marc>
    <call>
        <item>
            <numberOfHolds>4</numberOfHolds>
            <type>LOAN</type>
        </item>
    </call>
</catalog>
</report>
```

I have a style sheet that looks like this and it gives the intended result:
[Hold ratio output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riQvy.png).
Now I wonder if it's not possible to refine it a little more.
I want to filter the result so it only shows if the ratio is equal to or greater than three. 
I googled but couldn't find a solution that was spot on - but I guess it's either for-each or apply-template?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <catalog>
    <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog">
    <xsl:sort select="call/item/numberOfHolds div count(call/item [type='LOAN'])" order="descending" />
    <ratioline>
        <Title><xsl:value-of select="substring(marc/marcEntry[@tag='245'],1,30)"/></Title>
        <numberOfHolds><xsl:value-of select="call/item/numberOfHolds"/></numberOfHolds>
        <numberOfItemsSelectedType><xsl:value-of select="count(call/item[type='LOAN'])"/></numberOfItemsSelectedType>
            <ratio><xsl:value-of select="format-number(call/item/numberOfHolds div count(call/item[type='FLYTANDE' or type='HEMLAN']), '00.##')" /></ratio>
        </ratioline>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </catalog>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*Title one has four holds on two items*" Why four? There are two items, each with its own hold value - which one do you pick and why?

Comment: Yes, I know - it a weird value that comes from our library system. There are four holds on the title, but the value is repeated for each item. A good example of bad formatting :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start off by defining a parameter to hold your value of 3

```
<xsl:param name="min" select="3" />
```

To filter on it, you can first define a variable within the `xsl:for-each` to hold the ratio

```
<xsl:variable name="ratio" select="call/item/numberOfHolds div count(call/item [type='LOAN'])" />
```

Then you can use an `xsl:if` to test the ratio is greater or equal to your parameter

```
<xsl:if test="$ratio >= $min">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="min" select="3" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <catalog>
    <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog">
    <xsl:sort select="call/item/numberOfHolds div count(call/item [type='LOAN'])" order="descending" />
        <xsl:variable name="ratio" select="call/item/numberOfHolds div count(call/item [type='LOAN'])" />
        <xsl:if test="$ratio >= $min">
        <ratioline>
            <Title><xsl:value-of select="substring(marc/marcEntry[@tag='245'],1,30)"/></Title>
            <numberOfHolds>
                <xsl:value-of select="call/item/numberOfHolds"/>
            </numberOfHolds>
            <numberOfItemsSelectedType>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(call/item[type='LOAN'])"/>
            </numberOfItemsSelectedType>
            <ratio>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($ratio, '00.##')" />
            </ratio>
        </ratioline>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </catalog>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```